# How to represent partially nullable foreign keys?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, composite-key

Say that you want to store contact phone numbers, people, and households in a database. Every person belongs to exactly one household. A phone number may be associated with a particular individual in a household, or may be a general number for the household. These relationships are partially expressed in the following Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD (
    HOUSEHOLD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    PERSON_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    HOUSEHOLD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_HOUSEHOLD
        FOREIGN KEY (HOUSEHOLD_ID)
        REFERENCES HOUSEHOLD (HOUSEHOLD_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CONTACT_PHONE (
    PHONE_NUMBER CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    HOUSEHOLD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PERSON_ID INTEGER NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PHONE_HOUSEHOLD
        FOREIGN KEY (HOUSEHOLD_ID)
        REFERENCES HOUSEHOLD (HOUSEHOLD_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PHONE_PERSON
        FOREIGN KEY (PERSON_ID)
        REFERENCES PERSON (PERSON_ID)
);
```

The foreign keys and NULL/NOT NULL constraints ensure that every person belongs to exactly one household, that every contact phone is associated with exactly one household, and that a contact phone may or may not be associated with person. One thing that they do not prevent is a phone number that is associated with one household, and with a person who belongs to a different household. Is there a standard way to express this kind of relationship using database constraints? The example given is for Oracle, but solutions for other database platforms would be welcome, as well.

Comment: The point of phone numbers and households was simply to give an example of the relationship in question; another example would be countries, states (each of which is in a country), and cities (each of which is in a country and maybe a state in that same country).

Adding the phone number as a column to both tables, even with unique constraints, would not prevent associating it with one household, and then with a person belonging to a second household.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to have a foreign key to the HOUSEHOLD_ID and PERSON_ID columns of the PERSON table, but don't want it to be checked if the PERSON_ID column of the CONTACT_PHONE table is NULL.  The solution is to create a virtual/computed column that replicates HOUSEHOLD_ID, but only when PERSON_ID is not NULL, then use it in the foreign key instead of HOUSEHOLD_ID:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTACT_PHONE (
    PHONE_NUMBER CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    HOUSEHOLD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PERSON_ID INTEGER NULL,
    PERSON_HOUSEHOLD_ID GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        CAST(DECODE(PERSON_ID, NULL, NULL, HOUSEHOLD_ID) AS INTEGER)
    ) VIRTUAL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PHONE_HOUSEHOLD
        FOREIGN KEY (HOUSEHOLD_ID)
        REFERENCES HOUSEHOLD (HOUSEHOLD_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PHONE_PERSON
        FOREIGN KEY (PERSON_HOUSEHOLD_ID, PERSON_ID)
        REFERENCES PERSON (HOUSEHOLD_ID, PERSON_ID)
);
```

In this way, when PERSON_ID is not NULL, PERSON_HOUSEHOLD_ID will be the same as HOUSEHOLD_ID, and FK_PHONE_PERSON will be checked normally.

But, when PERSON_ID is NULL, PERSON_HOUSEHOLD_ID will also be NULL. Since both of the local columns participating in FK_PHONE_PERSON are NULL, the constraint will not be checked.